Really weird and unwanted bending with automatic weights
I make models, and sometimes for seemingly no reason, when I try to make a rig for the hand, the rig decides to bend the top part when I'm posing the bottom part, anyone know how to help? Thanks in advance
Here's a video example on my google drive because the regular upload service isn't working for me for some reason.

Hello, I've also noticed that but I guess you need to correct it in Weight Paint mode or remove these vertices from the vertex group it should not be part of

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

What you're showing in your video isn't weird.  It's pretty normal.  The top verts have influence from the bottom bone because they're close and because there are no intervening divots to block the bone heat.  I'd recommend focusing on your actual problem rather than trying to oversimplify it.  As an aside, doing your armature manipulations in object mode rather than armature edit mode is dangerous.  You should be weighting meshes with applied transforms, to armatures with applied transforms.
